# Need an alternate idiom for "Riding the coattails"

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I need an alternate idiom for “Riding the coattails”.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ride-on-the-coattails-of

Usage would be a blog title similar to:

> Grow your apps by riding on the coattails of iOS 10 and Android Nougat launch

I wanted to use it in a summary without reusing the idiom “Riding the coattails”

Comment: *Ride on X's shoulders?* *Be towed along in X's wake*? *Attach yourself to X's star?* *Climb on X's bandwagon?*

Comment: Why do you need an alternate idiom? What is the context where you plan to use it? Why don't you want to use the idiom "riding the coattails"? Give details!

Comment: There are idioms along the lines of "hitch your wagon to that".

Comment: Phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research. [(more¹)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) [(more²)](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info) [(more³)](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/3226/14073)

Answer (score 3):

Drafting in their wake would be another.

> **Draft**
>
> To follow another cyclist (or motor vehicle) so closely that the leading vehicle takes the brunt of the wind resistance, and acts as a
>   windbreak for the drafting cyclist.
>
> Since air resistance is the major limitation on bicycle speed, many of the tactics used in bicycle racing are based on exploiting
>   this effect.  [Sheldon](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_dr-z.html#draft)